# Can you get the benefit of Last Legion Officer without spending a healing surge?

Tags: dnd-4e

The feat Last Legion Officer reads as follows:

> Benefit: When you use a power that would enable an ally to spend a
>   healing surge, that ally can also choose to shift 1 square as a free
>   action or gain a +2 bonus to AC and Reflex until the start of his or
>   her next turn.

If a warlord uses Inspiring Word with this feat, can the target choose not to spend a healing surge but still gain the effect from the feat?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I'm no more sure about it because of how the feat is worded. Inspiring Word does something if the target spends a surge. Is Last Legion Officer's *also* referring to the effect (He can spend a surge and *gain 1d6 hp and also can choose*) or to the power (He can spend a surge and *gain 1d6 hp*, he also *can choose*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** Inspiring Word grants the *option* to spend a healing surge, and Last Legion Officer triggers off of granting such options, not on the healing surges actually being spent.

It sounds like a waste of an action (shift 1 or +2 AC/Reflex isn't much of an effect on its own), but I can imagine a few specialized situations where it might be useful. Perhaps setting up a flank or stepping on a trigger plate would be more useful, rarely, than whatever else you might accomplish on your turn.